# How to convert a Base10 number to a Base64 number with custom alphabet?

Tags: python, integer, base64

I'm writing a program that needs to be able to convert a base10 number to a base64 number, and back again using this alphabet:

```
"0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM. "
```

I've looked at other stack overflow questions, but none of those solutions work. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PedroLobito using the ```int()``` function, however that only goes up to base36, and I've tried using the ```string.maketrans``` function with base64 to make a custom alphabet, however my version of the ```string``` module does not support the ```.maketrans``` function

Comment: Welp, question got closed. Looks like I'm posting this question on reddit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
s = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM. "
def encode(n):
  ans = ''
  if n == 0:
    ans = s[0]
  else:
    while n:
      r, n = n % 64, n // 64
      ans += s[r]
  return ans[::-1]

def decode(n):
  ans, m = 0, 1
  for char in n[::-1]:
    ans += s.index(char) * m
    m *= 64
  return ans

print(encode(987654321))
print(decode('VZEnF'))
```

**Output:**

```
VZEnF
987654321
```

Comment: what if `n = 0`? Also, this seems to build the string backwards. `n = 66` => `21` instead of `12`

Comment: @komatiraju032 How do I do this in reverse?

Comment: @Python_Person sorry i forgot to reverse the string

Comment: @MarkMeyer thanks for the inputs really helpful

Comment: @komatiraju032 Ok, thanks for fixing the reversal, but how do I turn it back to base10?

Comment: @Python_Person i have added the decode method check once

Comment: @Python_Person You should accept this answer as correct because it does what you've asked for. Before asking the next question, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)